# in zsh, strip and add a suffix in a single glob pattern

Tags: zsh, wildcards

Suppose I have a file named `foo.md.md` (the reason for the double suffix will become apparent).

```
$ print *.md(om[1]) # Get the most recent .md file
foo.md.md

$ print *.md(om[1]:r) # Strip the suffix
foo.md

$ print *.md(om[1]:r).docx # Try to add a suffix -- oops that doesn't work
zsh: no matches found: *.md(om[1]:r).docx

$ print *.md(om[1]:s/.md/.docx/) # Try another way -- also falls short
foo.docx.md

$ f=(*.md(om[1])); print ${f:r}.docx # Store it in a variable -- works but verbose
foo.md.docx
```

It seems everything would be good if I could somehow get zsh to treat `*.md(om[1]:r)` as a complete pattern before adding a new suffix to it. Alternatively, if there were some way to anchor the `:s///` modifier to the end of the string.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that you can anchor the `:s/l/r` modifier if you enable the `HIST_SUBST_PATTERN` option:

```
~ % print -r -- *.md(om[1]:s/.md/.docx)
foo.docx.md
 ~ % print -r -- *.md(om[1]:s/%.md/.docx)
foo.md.md
 ~ % setopt histsubstpattern
 ~ % print -r -- *.md(om[1]:s/%.md/.docx)
foo.md.docx
```

Don't forget the `--` (also works with `-`), or you're introducing a command injection vulnerability! Omitting `-r` likely doesn't make sense either.

Comment: These are all great answers, but this seems to be the tersest.

Answer (score 7):

Another approach is to use an anonymous function to do further modifications using parameter expansion operators on `$@` (aka `$argv`):

```
(){print -r -- ${^@:r}.docx} *.md(om[1])
```

That saves using a temporary array variable. Here the `^` would only be needed if `$@` contained more than one element. For one element like here, that can be simplified to:

```
(){print -r -- $@:r.docx} *.md(om[1])
```

Or, as suggested by @Gairfowl in comments:

```
(){print -r -- $1:r.docx} *.md(om)
```

Don't forget the `--` (also works with `-`), or you're introducing a command injection vulnerability! Omitting `-r` likely doesn't make sense either.

Comment: Slightly shorter variant: `(){print -r -- $1:r.docx} *.md(om)`

Answer (score 6):

You could use the `e`*string* [glob qualifier](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) and change the value of `REPLY` e.g.

```
print -r -- *.md(om[1]e_'REPLY=${REPLY:r}.docx'_)
```

Don't forget the `--` (also works with `-`), or you're introducing a command injection vulnerability! Omitting `-r` likely doesn't make sense either.